# Writing files to HFS+ drive from Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, hfs+

Is it possible to write/edit files on HFS+ drive from Linux? Yes I need to disable journaling but how can I disable journaling from Linux? I dont have access to mac.

Or any tool available for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your /etc/fstab to include this as the last item and it should mount the drive with read/write permissions (the items in bold are universal and the 1st two need to match your installation.  In this example, my device is /dev/sda3, my mount location is /mnt/common, my user id/group id is 1000 (default in Ubuntu, change if yours is different) :

/dev/sda3 /mnt/common **hfsplus user,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0**

You may need to adjust permissions on your mount location (/mnt/common in this example).  The following would set read/write to everyone, but I would adjust to only allow access to specific people/groups instead of for everyone for security.

sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/common

Comment: What about for HFS+ filesystems on thumbdrives, where `fstab` isn't an option?

Answer (score 0):

By Linux I am going to assume you are using Ubuntu or another Debian based flavor. If this is the case then use the synaptic package repository viewer/installer tool (or a similar product in other versions) and do a search for HFS. I would assume similar to NTFS support there will be either Linux built kernel modules that can be installed OR more commonly a FUSE plugin that will be installable. Afterwards you may have to restart your computer, but them mounting an HFS drive should be automatic or easy to do from the "mount" command.